# Turn off input empty warning on Chrome/Firefox

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, symfony

If you have an input with `required="required"` defined, Firefox and Chrome make a little warning that it can't be empty at submittion. How can I turn this off for development? I'm using Symfony2 and everything is generate so I don't know how to add novalidate attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each and every form type has a [`required`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/form.html#required) option which controls whether the `required` attribute is rendered or not. You can simply tell the builder not to render the `required` attribute.

```
/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('myField', null, array('required' => false))
    ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, you have to use `novalidate`. It's easy to set this in symfony2, as you have to add it to the `form` tag. Here an example of a form in twig.

```
<form action="{{ path('wege_route') }}" method="post" novalidate>
    {{ form_widget(form) }}
    <p>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </p>
</form>
```

Comment: In my layout, I use to include a JS script if i'm in dev environment : https://github.com/alterphp/DeveloperBundle/blob/master/Resources/public/js/dev.js

Comment: So I can't set it somehow like $form->novalidate(true); ?

Comment: If you already use 2.3 you can possibly pass it in to the createForm method as described here - http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#changing-the-action-and-method-of-a-form

Not tested example:
$this->createForm(new TaskType(), $task, array(
    'novalidate' => 'novalidate'
));

Comment: Otherwise you may try PéCé's interesting solution